# Can a Mars orbiter mass only 50 kg?

Tags: propulsion, delta-v, ion-thruster, electric-propulsion, mars-orbiters

A [press release](https://virginorbit.com/satrevolution-virgin-orbit-and-polish-universities-establish-mars-consortium/)
by the SatRevolution consortium says that it plans to send cubesats "as small as 50 kg" to Mars
to "conduct a variety of valuable science."  So that means orbiting, not just a flyby like MarCO-A and MarCO-B on 2018 Nov 26.

50 kg is a twentieth the mass of previous Mars orbiters.
How could something this lightweight attain Mars orbit?  The required delta V is about [**3 km/s**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v_budget#Delta-vs_between_Earth,_Moon_and_Mars)
(there's no Oberth effect shortcut for an electric thruster).

Deep Space 1's [ion thruster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_thruster) achieved 4.3 km/s from 74 kg of xenon propellant,
or **0.058 km/s per kg**.  [Dawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_(spacecraft)#Specifications) 
was slightly less fuel efficient: 11.5 km/s from 247 kg, or 0.046 km/s per kg.

At 0.058 km/s per kg,
a Mars orbiter would need 3 / 0.058 = 51 kg of fuel, more than the mass of the entire proposed spacecraft.

Have thrusters improved so much since those launches that a 50 kg all-up weight is plausible?

---

Related buzzword (not yet a tag): tankage fraction.
18-page analysis of this kind of propulsion for orbit transfers: http://www.umich.edu/~peplweb/pdf/AIAA-96-2973.pdf

Comment: Is that the one using the solid iodine propellant instead of xenon? Could be wrong.

Comment: I hadn't heard what kind of thrusters.  Sounds intriguing, though.

Comment: It may not be this one- but I know that was a newer paper about the feasibility of solid iodine propellant as a stand in for Xenon at a small loss in ISP. Would suprise me if someone was trying to test it- seems like it mitigated a lot of storage issues at the cost of complexity in the thruster itself.

Comment: Atmospheric braking is not mentioned in this press release, nor is it discarded, still its an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The amount of propellant required to achieve a certain delta-V is dependent on the ratio between the starting and ending mass of the spacecraft, according to the [Tsiolkovsky rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation); a given thruster and fuel supply will get you more delta-V on a smaller spacecraft and less delta-V on a larger one. That is, 0.058 km/s per kg is not an inherent property of DS1's ion thruster.

Furthermore, 3 km/s is what you need to get from *Earth escape* to Mars orbit; if the launcher can put the spacecraft on a Mars intercept trajectory, the spacecraft itself needs only about 1.5 km/s of delta-V to get into orbit.

By the rocket equation, I think you need only around 3 kg of propellant with a 25 km/s exhaust velocity ion engine for a 50 kg spacecraft to obtain the required delta-V to get into orbit.

Comment: 1, Thanks for catching my oversimplifications.  2, A pity the MarCO's didn't have a few extra kg to become orbiters themselves!

Comment: The fixed mass of the thruster and, especially, its power supply does tend to dominate the mass of propellant at such small sizes; a chemical thruster might be more capable in a 50kg spacecraft despite having only 1/10 the specific impulse.